# Commerce account pane email change

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal 7 with commerce module. In the commerce shipping pane I have created a new email filed through `admin -> store -> Customer profiles -> Shipping Information` and it is displaying in the shipping section that’s all fine.

Now what I have to do here is use this email while creating the account for anonymous users instead of using email from the account pane and also I need to hide the email filed in account pane.  Can anyone guide me how to implement this? Thanks in advance.

Ratheesh

Comment: Anonymous users will be asked to enter an email address anyway when checking out, what is wrong with using the default email field? You seem to be making things harder for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue like adding a submit handler function when click on continue button click. Code is provided below

```
your-module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   global $user;
   if(!$user->name){
      $form['account']['login']['mail']['#required'] = 0;
      $form['account']['login']['mail']['#prefix'] = '<div style="display: none;">';
      $form['account']['login']['mail']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
      array_unshift($form['buttons']['continue']['#validate'], 'your-module_submit_handler');
    }
}

your-module_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form_state['values']['account']['login']['mail'] = $form['customer_profile_shipping']['field_email']['und'][0]['value']['#value'];
}
```